# How can I redo a pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had a hotfix branch that I merged to master.  After that another team member merged the release branch to master and overwrote my changes. I did not update the release branch since that was already passed in testing and my changes were isolated.  Is there a way to use the same pull request again and merge that to master?

Comment: there should have been a conflict.

Comment: you could cherry pick yoru commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a bad merge undid your changes? Because the commits with your changes are in the master branch still, so you can't exactly perform the merge again.

I think you'll have to manually make your changes again and create a new pull request.

Comment: We can revert PR directly. :)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as a merge from other branches were now committed.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting a pull request on GitHub creates a new pull request that contains one revert of the merge commit from the original merged pull request.

This should help you. https://help.github.com/en/articles/reverting-a-pull-request

Its easy.